# Using Conditional statement for of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, for-loop

I'm building a react native application that uses checks if the Buying and Selling prices of Currency pairs have reached user-set thresholds then send a message that the user has set. There are two price thresholds that are rendered conditionally: BuyThreshold price which is the price that the user wants to be notified if it is equal to the current market buying price E.G 1.12343 of a currency pair e.g EURUSD. The other threshold is the sell threshold which is the price at which the user wants to be notified if it is equal to the current market selling price E.G 1.12330 of a currency pair e.g EURUSD
The function is not checking if the thresholds are being reached by the market buying or selling price. How can i do it? Below is the code:

```
      const [clickedindex, setClickedIndex]  = useState(0)
function checkCondition({BuyThreshold, SellThreshold, SMSMessage}) {
  const BuyingPrice = {...currency.data.prices[clickedindex].BuyingPrice}
  const SellingPrice = {...currency.data.prices[clickedindex].SellingPrice}
  const currencypair = {...currency.data.prices.instrument}
  
  const BuyThresholdarray = []
  const SellThreshhold =[]

  BuyThresholdarray.push(BuyThreshold)

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < BuyThresholdarray.length; i++) {
  console.log(BuyThresholdarray[i])
    if(SelectedCurrencyPair) {
      if (BuyingPrice >= BuyThresholdarray[i]) {
        return(
        console.log(SMSMessage)
        )
      }
      else {
        console.log("ALert ")
      }
    }  
  }
}, 1000);

    

        <View>
                    {
                    // Mapping of the actual currency pairs and their ask and bid prices respectively
                    currency.data.prices && currency.data.prices.map((prices, index) => {
                        return (
              <ListItem
                key={index}
                onPress = {() => {setModalOpen(true);setClickedIndex(index);}} 
                bottomDivider>
                <ListItem.Content>
                    <ListItem.Title>
                    {data.prices[index].instrument}        {data.prices[index].BuyingPrice}         {data.prices[index].SellingPrice}
                    </ListItem.Title>
                </ListItem.Content>
              </ListItem>     
                        )
                    })
        }
                </View>
    // Modal with textinputs for the Buy and Sell Thresholds
    <Modal
              visible={modalopen}
              transparent={true}
              animationType={"fade"}
              >
                
                    <Text style={{textAlign: "center", fontWeight: "bold"}}>
                      Create Alert On: 
                    </Text>          
                    <Text style={{textAlign: "center", fontWeight: "bold"}}>
                   {data.prices[clickedindex].instrument}
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
                  {data.prices[clickedindex].BuyingPrice}/{data.prices[clickedindex].SellingPrice}
                  </Text>
                  
                  <Card.Divider/>
    
                  <View>
                    <View>
                    <Picker
                      mode= "dropdown"
                selectedValue={selectedValue}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>setSelectedValue(itemValue) }
              >
                <Picker.Item label="BuyPrice" value="BuyPrice" /> 
                <Picker.Item label="SellPrice" value="SellPrice" />
                
              </Picker>
    
                    </View>
                  
              {
                selectedValue === "BuyPrice" ? 
                <TextInput
                      style={styles.textInputStyle}
                      value={BuyThreshold}
                      onChangeText = {(BuyThreshold) => setBuyThreshhold(BuyThreshold)}
                      placeholder="BuyThreshhold"
                      placeholderTextColor="#60605e"
                      numeric
                      clearButtonMode='always'
                      keyboardType='decimal-pad'    
                    /> : 
                    <TextInput
                      style={styles.textInputStyle}
                      value={SellThreshold}
                      onChangeText = {(SellThreshhold) => setSellThreshhold(SellThreshhold)}
                      placeholder="Sell Threshhold"
                      placeholderTextColor="#60605e"
                      numeric
                      clearButtonMode='always'
                      keyboardType='decimal-pad'    
                    />
                 
    
              }
                  </View>
                 
                  <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent:"center" }}>
                  
                    <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
                      <TextInput
                      style={styles.messageStyle}
                      value={SMSMessage}
                      onChangeText = {(SMSMessage) => setSMSMessage(SMSMessage)}
                      placeholder="Message"
                      clearButtonMode='always'
    
                      placeholderTextColor="#60605e"
                    />
    
                    </View>
                  </View>  
                  <View style={{flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "center"}}>
                    <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
                   onPress={() => {
                     if(SMSMessage.length === 0)
                     {
                       Alert.alert("Incomplete", "Enter your Alert Message")
                       return ;
                     }
                      createAlert();
                      checkCondition({BuyThreshold, SellThreshold, SMSMessage});
                      setModalOpen(false);
                      showToastWithGravityAndOffset();} }
                      >
                       <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>OK</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress ={() => setModalOpen(false)}>
                        <Text>Close</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
    
                    </View>
                    </View>  
                  </View>
                </View>
              </Modal>
```

Comment: Where is `SelectedCurrencyPair` defined? Is that supposed to be `currencypair`?

Comment: This is not valid javaScript: `const SellingPrice = {data.prices.SellingPrice}` and also what is your question?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Do you want `SellingPrice` and `BuyingPrice` to be arrays? I think you want to set these as: `const { SellingPrice, BuyingPrice } = data.prices;` Also you would want to check `if(SelectedCurrencyPair.length > 0) {` instead because an empty array is a truthy value in JavaScript. That's a start. Would need more information to fully solve (can you create a functioning code pen with similar dummy data)?

Comment: Let me add mode code for context

Comment: I have edited the code for context